# Reactjs update table

Tags: json, reactjs

I have 2 scripts:

- table.js : renders data table
- os.js : returns os name

Data in table is being loaded using json. Sample json:

```
[
  {"server":"server1.com"},
  {"server":"server2.com"}
]
```

On button click, table should check servername and update the corresponding os data. How can I do this?

table.js:

```js
import getOS from "./os.js";

class TableRow extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);

   this.state= {label: ''};

   this.update = this.update.bind(this);
  }

  update(){
    getOS(servername);
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;

    const list = data.map(adata => {
      return (
        <tr>
          <td key={adata.server}>{adata.server}</td>
          <td key={adata.os}></td>
        </tr>
      )//return
    })//regionslist

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
      { list }
      <Button size="sm" type="submit" onClick= {this.update}>
            Get Details
      </Button>
      </React.Fragment>
    );//return
  } //render
} //class
```

Comment: so what does getOS function does? Does it returns the data that you want to display?

Comment: yes...it just returns the OS version once servername is passed to it...for eg for server1 it will return osname as 'Linux'.

Comment: and where do you get servername from right now?

Comment: servername will be the data in this row : <td key={adata.server}>{adata.server}</td> ....  trying to find out a way to get the value of this variable i.e. servername

Comment: so wait... You want to find a way to pass that data to `this.update` function or you want to use that data to map and display rows?

Comment: i want to use the data from <td key={adata.server}>{adata.server}</td> .. pass it to getOS(...) function and update <td key={adata.os}></td> with the details returned from getOS function.

Comment: do you consider placing button inside mapped array? Otherwise you will need to use your state.

Comment: If you are talking about placing the button inside const list... then no...that would give separate button for each row... need to have single button at bottom of page that will update the data.

Comment: then how will "react" know which data you want to use?

Comment: is it possible to convert column in the table into an array in reactjs?

Comment: It would be possible to create array consisting data from the table and even filter it to a single column, but I believe it is wrong approach to your problem

Comment: i implemented a way using jquery...however couldn't get it done via reactjs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return button in every row, you can do it like this:

```
class TableRow extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { label: '', data: this.props.data };
  }

  update = (servername) => {
    const data = getOS(servername);
    this.setState({ data });
  };

  render() {
    return this.state.data.forEach((adata) => {
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <tr>
            <td key={adata.server}>{adata.server}</td>
            <td key={adata.os} />
          </tr>
          <Button size="sm" type="submit" onClick={this.update(adata.server)}>
            Get Details
          </Button>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    }); //return
  } //render
} //class
```